# Force an MSI to setup with a specific account

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I have an MSI setup file edited with ORCA.

I would like to be able to personnalize it ( with orca ? ) in order to setup it with a specific account (specifing user and password).

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Comment: You need to explain what "setup it with a specific account" means. Does it mean install with that user account? Install a service with that account? Have the account somewhere in the MSI file, but then what do you want to do with it. Note that there doesn't need to be anything in the MSI file because you can install it as msiexec /I <msi file> MYUSER=User MYPASS=pass, and that data can be used at install time. Having a password in the MSI file means that it may too exposed to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the MSI installation - how it was created. I mean a logic for specifing username and password.
Sometimes, you can find Username and Password as Properties in Property table, sometimes they exist only in dialog window editboxes and sometimes they do not exist in MSI at all.
Please look for similar names in Property table or check dialog windows.
[InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/) will be more useful instead of Orca here, because it can create relations beetween Windows Installer elements. So, you can find your properties quicklier.